# Insufficient cluster resources to launch trial - has only 0 GPUs

Tags: python, pytorch, ray, ray-tune

I am following [this](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/hyperparameter_tuning_tutorial.html) tutorial (which is basically [this](https://docs.ray.io/en/master/tune/tutorials/tune-pytorch-cifar.html)) in order to use ray tune for hyperparemeter optimization. My model is training fine on the GPU without the optimization but now I want to optimize.

I applied the tutorial to my code but when I try to kick off the thing:

```py
result = tune.run(
    train,
    resources_per_trial={"gpu": 1},
    config=config,
    num_samples=10,
    scheduler=scheduler,
    progress_reporter=reporter,
    checkpoint_at_end=False,
)
```

I'm stuck with:

> TuneError: Insufficient cluster resources to launch trial: trial requested 1 CPUs, 1 GPUs, but the cluster has only 6 CPUs, 0 GPUs, 12.74 GiB heap, 4.39 GiB objects (1.0 node:XXX).

But then again, when I take a look at the ray dashboard:

[image: ray dashboard]

there clearly are both GPUs listed.

**Why isn't ray tune seeing my GPUs? How do I make this work?**

Specs:

```
GPU 0: TITAN Xp
GPU 1: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti
CUDA 10.1
Python 3.7
PyTorch 1.7
Debian 9.12
ray tune 1.0.1.post1
```

//edit:

```py
ray.init(num_gpus=1)
ray.get_gpu_ids()
```

> []

Comment: Try starting ray on the terminal with `ray start --head` and then in your python script use `ray.init(address='auto')`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking out placement_strategy and max_t variables.
First can cause freezes dependent on your system specification and second can just exceed total time for computation